# 画面遷移をしてもtableviewの値を維持したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

Objective-cでiOS向けのアプリを作っています．
Navigation Controllerを使って，画面1と画面2を遷移するプログラムを作っています．
画面2では，Tableviewに+ボタンで値を追加していきます．
この時，画面1に遷移すると画面2にTableviewの値がすべてクリアされてしまいます．
この場合，どのようにして画面2のTableviewの値を保持すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 方法はいくつもあります。大別して、メモリ上にデータを保持する方法と、ディスク上にファイルとして保持する方法に分けられるでしょう。前者はアプリが起動しているあいだ、データを保持することができますが、アプリを終了したら、データも消えます。後者はほぼ永続的にデータを保持することができますが、メモリ上にロードし、適切なタイミングでメモリ上から書き戻す（更新する）手間が必要です。あなたのいう「画面2のTableviewの値」の性質を考えて、最適な方法を選択し、それを質問文に反映していただけたらと思います。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます．
IRKitのiOS-SDKを使って，NSObject型変数に値を追加しています．
https://github.com/irkit/ios-sdk/tree/master/Minimal/Minimal
↑こちらにある，MMSignalsDataSource.mとMMViewController.mを使っています．
ここで，IRSignal *signalとして値を保存していると思うのですが，当方よく分かっておりません．
このsignalの値をUserDefaultとして保存し，一度保存した値が常時表示，送信できるようにしたいです．

Comment: いや、だからそういうことを、コメント欄にでなく、質問文としてお書きくださいと申し上げているわけで……。回答だけでなく、質問の質も向上させ、後進の役に立つ質の高い情報源にすることが、ここの理念らしいので、それに従うべきだと思います。そしてコードの掲示も、質問の質の向上ということでは重要だと思います。

Comment: @nyagato_00 もしiOSアプリ作成が始めてであれば、IRKitをいきなり使うのではなく、簡単なテーブルビューだけのアプリを作成してみてはどうでしょうか？公式リファレンスの[iOS Table View プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/TableView_iPhone.pdf)が参考になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

とりあえずということで、お手軽にNavigation Controllerのクラス変数を使ってみてはどうでしょうか？

NavigationController.hで、

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count;
```

としておいて、このNavigation Controllerにぶら下がっているView Controllerなどから、

```
NavigationController *nc = (NavigationController *)self.navigationController;
NSInteger count = nc.count; //read
nc.count = count+100;       //write
```

とすれば読み書きできます。